# Publishing recreational research

Tags: soft-question, publishing

I wanted to know if there is any mathematical journal, like the "Journal of Recreational Mathematics", which is currently still publishing and is focused on light-hearted and fun problems and proofs. Which might be nice to read but does not necessarily contain important mathematical results.

I am familiar with good practices during the publishing process. So I do not need pointers on that, just a list of journal names. 
And I am also aware of the existence of [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/), which could be one possible place to publish, but a journal with a peer reviewing community seems a nicer solution.

The motivation of the question is the following:  I am a masters student in Physics and sometimes I find myself analyzing some mathematical problem for fun. The problems are not especially difficult and the analysis I do is mostly superficial, since I often use numeric approaches (as physicists do). So I do not think that they are serious research worth of attention, but the results sometimes seem interesting or peculiar enough that one would have fun reading them.

Comment: I think most journals don't have any requirement that you should be employed at any research institution or in a research oriented role to submit manuscripts to them.

Comment: As you may know association journals like the Mathematical Gazette or the American Mathematical Monthly allow you submit novel problems along with a solution, so if your solution is correct, the problem itself can be published for others to solve.

Comment: Maybe you will do a self answer on this site?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand you one of the Mathematical Association of America journals:

- [The American Mathematical Monthly](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly)
- [Mathematics Magazine](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/mathematics-magazine)
- [The College Mathematics Journal](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal)